# Is it possible to ignore/autoyes all disk space prompts in an apt-get installation?

Tags: apt-get, ubuntu-13.10

Is it possible to ignore/autoyes all disk space prompts in an apt-get installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-get install -y <package name>
```